# List of Replica Symmetry results for different models?

Tags: pr.probability, mp.mathematical-physics, computational-complexity, physics, statistical-physics

Does anyone know of a good source that might have a list of problems or models along with what kind of replica symmetry they are conjectured to have?

I am aware of some of the more famous results, e.g. Sherrington-Kirkpatrick spin glass model and the corresponding spherical model being FRSB (Full Replica Symmetry Breaking) and K-SAT being 1-RSB, but I am wondering if there is some kind of compendium somewhere of these kinds of results/conjectures.

(p.s. also posted this on physics stack exchange; if that isn't Kosher or there is an official way to merge the questions let me know. I am new to this)